# How to get number of pages in kendo pdfExport

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, export-to-pdf

I have following code

```
kendo.drawing.drawDOM(tempContainer, {
    paperSize: "A4",
    landscape: false,
    template: $("#page-template").html()
}).then(function(group) {
    //here I need total number of pages produced by kendo
    return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group);
}).done(function(data) {
    //or maybe here?
});
```

Is there any way to get total number of pages in created pdf file? I mean pure javascript solution without any external libraries. I am using kendo-ui library only.

Answer (score 0):

Along with paperSize and landscape, add AllPages.like allPages: true,
This will export all the pages from grid and also will provide page numbers on each page like if pdf is of 5 pages,then page numbers will be 1/5, 2/5 and so on.

Please refer dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/iqAMOnis

Comment: Exported container in my case is not a grid. This is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

to get the number of pages, try using `group.children.length`